# The best way to convert web-page to pdf image

Tags: php, pdf

can any one tell me a simple way to convert web-page screen shot to pdf

Comment: Why not just send the person a link to the webpage?

Comment: @animuson Because probably that's not what he wants!
Think of a website that has tutorials, or news. The user just clicks "save to pdf" and he has a PDF generated "on the fly" that he can store on his computer/mobile/etc, for offline use. Very handy in certain situations.

EDIT: better re-reading the question... he speaks about "screenshot" so maybe you're right :)

Comment: Is this for use on an internal/dedicated server or for use on shared hosting? Solutions will vary accordingly. On internal/dedicated you could use Ghostscript to generate near perfect PDF output from HTML, on shared hosting this will probably not be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to do this from a desktop user standpoint
Windows: http://www.go2pdf.com/product.html
Linux: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/35022

If you mean form code then:
PHP:http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

But more information would definitely be useful :D

Answer (score 2):

http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/

http://www.expresspdf.com/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[PDFMyURLcom](http://pdfmyurl.com/), hands down.

Perfect rendering, except for some custom fonts.  Here's an example:

http://pdfmyurl.com?url=github.com/portfolio&-B=0mm&-T=0mm&-L=0mm&--margin-right=0mm&--page-size=A3&-O=Portrait.

Comment: Even though it's nice, it doesn't seem to be so perfect on complex sites : http://pdfmyurl.com/?url=standaard.be&-B=0mm&-T=0mm&-L=0mm&--margin-right=0mm&--page-size=A4&-O=Portrait

Answer (score 2):

Creating a PDF from HTML instead of letting the user just see the HTML should not be done without consideration. If you already have a usable HTML page you can display, ask yourself: what would the user benefit from having this in a PDF ? If the issue still stands, here are a few options:

- Use the well known but buggy [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). All you need is PHP, and it renders somewhat decent. They had some security problems but those went relatively unnoticed because no **big fish** is using it. No CSS support.
- Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which is absolutely great, supports CSS etc. Thing is, it requires access to the box. Oh, and another pesky little issue, X client libraries must be installed. Aside from that, it renders great and the PDF you are producing ends up looking a lot like the original page.
- If the HTML is dynamic (outputted by some script), have it outputted directly as a PDF, using [PDFLIB](http://www.pdflib.com/) or it's poor cousin [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).