# If the graphs and tables are client-side, how do I build a server-side pdf of those?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf, charts, telerik

While this question is about telerik controls, it applies to any client-side jQuery graphics library.

I have a website that produces charts and tables via jQuery libraries. So the browser display is really a munge of the json data returned from the server, css, and jquery graphics manipulations.

I need to be able to build a pdf file of the visuals (graph, table, etc) which seems like a natural for the server. My thought was to build the visuals as image files on the server then send to client and also build pdf.

Do any of the telerik controls allow for server-side export or save to image?
Is this how people usualy solve this problem? 
Is there an easier or more obvious way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816281/the-best-way-to-convert-web-page-to-pdf-image, though the answers were given over two years ago - things may have changed.

Comment: My question is architectural. I'm not interested in post-processing by a 3rd party product or service after the web page is drawn, I want to control the process from the start.

Comment: Found this sample code of Telerik Kendo that generates png images and then (with the inkscape.org library) generates a pdf. http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/dataviz/chart/kendo-ui-chart-export.aspx

Comment: For client computers under your control (ie. intranet architecture) you can arrange for them to print to pdf (needs appropriate print driver), using CSS @media rules to control what is printed, what is omitted and printer-friendly colors. A generalised solution (for internet users) would involve rendering/converting the page server-side then serving the resulting PDF to the user as an HTTP response. I didn't read the answers to the referenced question thoroughly enough to work out which category they fall into. As you can probably guess, I have only very limited experience in this area.

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot - thanks for the idea about css @media rules. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, the server must have images from which to generate the pdf from. I'm using a client-side javascript library which will send images back to the server of what it produces. I would prefer to build images on the server than ship client-side but that removes the interactivity of the client.

Once the images on are on the server, you can pump them into a pdf files. The Kendo example linked above uses http://inkscape.org/download/?lang=en as the pdf generation library on the server.